# Setup subversion 403 Forbidden

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I have setup subversion according to this how to: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-subversion-with-web-access-on-ubuntu/

So in the root directory of my server I have following folder: `/var/snv`. This folder will contain my svn repositories that I create this way

```
sudo svnadmin create /var/svn/myproject
```

Next I edited the `dav_svn.conf` file.

```
<Location /var/svn>

  DAV svn

  SVNParentPath /var/svn

  AuthType Basic
  Require valid-user
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd

</Location>
```

I try to access subversion via browser with `http://myRootServer.com/var/svn`. This asks me for username and password and when entering the correct data I get a 403 Forbidden error, `You don't have permission to access /var/svn on this server`.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying an `SVNParentPath`, the actual location of the path (in this case, `/var/svn/`) isn't a valid location to request - there's no mechanism for serving an index of the child repositories.

A request to a child repository directly (`/var/svn/myproject`) should yield an index page for that repository, and should not be giving a `403` after successful authentication.

Answer (score 3):

You can absolutely display a list of repositories using SVNParentPath.

You need to add the following to your apache configuration:

```
SVNListParentPath on
```